# Django CMS Contact Form

Tags: django, django-cms

Does Django CMS have a contact form plugin which when submitted will send an e-mail to both my e-mail and the submitter's e-mail?

I plan to have a form where the field only contains the submitter's name and e-mail then the submitter will receive an e-mail with an attached pdf

Answer (score 1):

There are plugins available, I've personally created my own in the past as every site had different requirements (form fields, captcha mechanism etc). There were some that offered captcha.

Here's one created recently, I haven't tested this personally: https://github.com/juliarizza/djangocms_contact_form

Another plugin last updated 2 years ago:
https://github.com/maccesch/cmsplugin-contact

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the only feature-complete version would be [aldryn-forms](https://github.com/divio/aldryn-forms/). Its UX is rather poor though, eg the email notifications for the admin should be enabled on the `Form` plugin, but the email notification for the user should be configured on the `Email field` plugin.

There's also a generic project template which utilizes this plugin along with its recaptcha v3 and bootstrap4 packages - https://gitlab.com/what-digital/djangocms-template